# Importing from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, import, vba

I have posted recently a Importing values from multiple sheets from one file into another file. I think I have the code to solve this but the problem is that I cannot see a place to integrate it.

My actual code is this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Path As String, Lstrw As Long
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Path = "C:\Users\DZPH8SH\Desktop\Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls"    'Change this to your company workbook path
Workbooks.Open (Path)

Set SourceWb = Workbooks("Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls")    'Change "Source" to the name of your company workbook

'Part that needs some adjustments in down below
Set TargetWb = Workbooks("Master_Atual_2015.xlsm") 'change the file address

Lstrw = SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
With SourceWb.Sheets(1)
    .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets(1).Range("A3")

End With
SourceWb.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And what I need to put in my code to make it copy information from both sheets is this:

```
Sub MoveData()
  Dim LastRow As Long, WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
  Set WS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
  LastRow = WS1.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
Intersect(WS1.Rows("2:" & LastRow), WS1.Range("D:D,F:F,I:I,M:N")).Copy WS2.Range("A3")
End Sub
```

this is a quote from the person that gave me the code hope it helps to find a correct place in the code because I'm not being able to find one.

> the following code will work from one sheet to a second sheet within the same workbook, so I would think all you have to do is qualify the Sheets properties in the two statements where WS1 and WS2 are Set (highlighted in blue) with the workbook references and the rest of the code should work from there

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? I do notice `WS1.Range("D:D,F:F,I:I,M:N")).Copy WS2.Range("A3")` should cause an error.1-the range is non-contiguous. 2-if you copy an entire column and try to paste it into A3, the column will not fit

Comment: That is the problem, I'm a newbie and I'm having problems integrating that piece of code with my own, Can't figure out the right place and It disrupts my code, due to the code not being modified in way that fits my expectations. He said, I just needed to make some changes and It would import the data from both sheets into my other sheet located in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a different way to do things. Here is another option.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim RangeArea As Range, x

    Set WS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    x = 0

    For Each RangeArea In WS1.Range("D:D,F:F,I:I,M:N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Areas
        RangeArea.Copy WS2.Range("A3").Offset(0, x)
        x = x + 1
    Next RangeArea

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for a possible solution to my problem, but I have a question, In what way could I integrate this with my current code, because I need my current code due to all the locations and to a almost complete code, of cells and paths to workbooks. And I took some time to make it. Can it be arrange in some way that both would be integrated?